# Rounding issue in openjdk8

Tags: java, number-formatting

I'm seeing something strange issue while using the `NumberFormat.format(double)` in **open jdk1.8.** I know there was an issue with rounding in the prior versions that was fixed in this version, but still something seems off.

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    double num = 16.34625;

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2); 
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);

            System.out.println("nf : " + nf.getRoundingMode());
            System.out.println("BigDecimal is " + new  BigDecimal(num).toString());     

    System.out.println("num after number format : " + nf.format(num));
}
```

Here's the actual result displayed:

```
nf : HALF_EVEN
num : 16.34625
BigDecimal is 16.346250000000001278976924368180334568023681640625
num after number format : 16.3463
```

But, I would have expected it to be rounded to 16.3462, since in HALF_EVEN mode, the digit to the left of the discarded number is even, so it should act as HALF_DOWN.

Here's the java doc to back this up (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN).

Comment: With HALF_EVEN rounding, it rounds to the nearest even number **if it's equidistant from both neighbors**.  But 16.346250000000001278976924368180334568023681640625 is closer to 16.3463 than it is to 16.3462.  You have the fact that floats and doubles can't accurately represent decimal numbers to thank for this.  Try creating the BigDecimal from a String representation of your number (i.e. "16.34625") to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Just replace `double num = 16.34625;` with `String num = "16.34625";` and see what happens…

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still a bit confused. I agree that the closest representation of the double 16.34625 is 16.346250000000001278976924368180334568023681640625. But, since the 5th digit after the decimal place is a '5' which is equidistant, then since its preceding digit is a '4' which is even, it should act as half_down, and the final result should have been 16.3462. If the preceding digit was an odd one, then it should act as half_up. Is that not right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to round off in the `BigInteger` itself. You can use the `setScale` method of that class.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(num).setScale(4,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
//16.3463
```

Comment: I'm not looking to get a certain number rounding. I was just curious to see why this was the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about everything. The only issue is, that your BigDecimal is not 16.34625, it's 16.346250000000001278976924368180334568023681640625. So the neighbours are not equidistant.